# database tables created in access and relationships to be created somewhere else?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, relationship, database-normalization

I am currently working on a project which has many tables with no relationships. I would like to know whether it is possible for tables to be created first and then relationships to be created for example through C# langauage or outside ms access (is that even possible?)

I have knowledge of normalisation. however, as I did not manage to find an answer on google I wanted to ask this question incase I start normalisation process and then later on find out that the relationships were already done via another method.

Thank you

Comment: I mean theoretically as long as the data integrity was upheld, so there are no foreign key errors, I can't see any reason you can't do that

Comment: so you can just create tables with the right keys and then do the relationships from another program? @SaggingRufus can you give me an example or a link please

Comment: something like this? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/creating-relations-in-ms-access-with-c-sharp

Comment: But then it would be wrong to have similar information in both tables?! e.g. name = R in tableA and name = R in tableB (if both tables are connected to each other) @SaggingRufus

Comment: I guess the relationships are "implicitly" implemented by the application code, but not explicitly defined (that would be visible in the database).

Comment: There are multiple ways to implement explicit relationships from C#, for example using DDL queries (like the link SaggingRufus shared), or using COM and DAO. If you ask a specific question, I can give a specific answer. None of them require your field names to be identical on both tables (afaik)

Comment: You are not clear. Do you mean you want to know how to *determine* whether the tables satisfy FK constraints, or what?

Answer (score 2):

I would use *DAO* as Erik suggests. Though I have no code to run it from C#, the VBA example here should demonstrate the steps needed:

```vb
' Creates and appends missing relations between the local tables.
' Note, that this will create a hidden index on the foreign table field.
' Returns True if success, False if not.
'
' 2017-11-14. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CreateLocalDataTableRelations() As Boolean

    Dim Database        As DAO.Database
    Dim Field           As DAO.Field
    Dim Relation        As DAO.Relation
    Dim Table           As DAO.TableDef
    Dim ForeignTable    As DAO.TableDef

    Dim RelationName    As String
    Dim Result          As Boolean

    Set Database = CurrentDb

    Set Table = Database.TableDefs("Country")
    Set ForeignTable = Database.TableDefs("Zone")
    RelationName = Table.Name & "_" & ForeignTable.Name
    If Not IsTableRelation(RelationName) Then
        ' Create and append relation RelationName.
            Set Relation = Database.CreateRelation(RelationName)
            Relation.Table = Table.Name
            Relation.ForeignTable = ForeignTable.Name
            Relation.Attributes = dbRelationUpdateCascade
                Set Field = Relation.CreateField("Code")
                Field.ForeignName = "CountryCode"
            Relation.Fields.Append Field
        Database.Relations.Append Relation
    End If

    Set Table = Database.TableDefs("Zone")
    Set ForeignTable = Database.TableDefs("Timezone")
    RelationName = Table.Name & "_" & ForeignTable.Name
    If Not IsTableRelation(RelationName) Then
        ' Create and append relation RelationName.
            Set Relation = Database.CreateRelation(RelationName)
            Relation.Table = Table.Name
            Relation.ForeignTable = ForeignTable.Name
            Relation.Attributes = dbRelationUpdateCascade
                Set Field = Relation.CreateField("ZoneId")
                Field.ForeignName = "ZoneId"
            Relation.Fields.Append Field
        Database.Relations.Append Relation
    End If

    Result = (Err.Number = ErrorNone)

    CreateLocalDataTableRelations = Result

End Function
```

and the helper function:

```vb
' Checks if a relation named RelationName exists.
' Returns True if it is found, False if not.
'
' 2017-11-14. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function IsTableRelation( _
    ByVal RelationName As String) _
    As Boolean

    Dim Relation    As DAO.Relation

    Dim Result      As Boolean

    For Each Relation In CurrentDb.Relations
        If Relation.Name = RelationName Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Result = Not (Relation Is Nothing)

    IsTableRelation = Result

End Function
```

Comment: Is `IsTableRelation` a UDF? If so, could you either provide it, or provide insight into what it does? I'm not familiar with that function.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Yes, missed that, sorry. It is a simple helper function. I have added it.